# Does placing a statement in quotes, invalidate the need to backshift?

Tags: backshifting, reported-speech

Is it correct to say the following sentence:

> A week ago I went to the shops to buy some butter and all of a sudden I saw that ‘two men are walking towards me’.

Here I used ‘are’ because the statement is inside the inverted commas. The same concept which is used in direct speech. Such as:

> John said to Kate, “I am hungry”.

So is it correct to use 'are' in the aforementioned scenario?

Comment: Not to be picky, just trying to help: butter is an uncountable noun so 'a butter' should be either 'some butter' or 'a *unit* of butter'... Same rule that applies to other substances like water.

Answer (score 4):

> I saw that ‘two men are walking towards me’.

That is incorrect. It's wrong for more than one reason

1. You would not say:  *John said to Kate that “I am hungry”.*

So we should remove the word 'that'.

2. *I saw "Two men are walking towards me".*

That is marginally better but not at all idiomatic because 'to see' is a subjective experience whereas quotes are used when relating an experience.

So you could say

*I saw two men walking towards me.*

or

*I thought to myself, "Two men are walking towards me"*.

or stretching things

*I realised, "Two men are walking towards me".*

Comment: A question that should be on ELL really ought not to be answered here: it sends the wrong message, and deos not help the OP in any but the most individual sense.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK :What about the sentence : A week ago I was sleeping and when I woke up I noticed "The clock is not working." SO, is this sentence idiomatically correct ?

Comment: No it's not idiomatic. The only reason I entertained  *I realised, "Two men..."* is that it could be interpreted as an internal dialog.  I don't see any way that *I noticed* can describe a dialog.  The only exception I can think of is if you saw a sign or note with the words, "The clock is not working." written on it.